# Open immersion from a proper scheme to a separated, irreducible scheme.

Tags: self-learning, schemes

Fix a scheme $S$ and let $X$ and $Y$ be $S$-schemes. Assume that $X$ is proper over $S$ and $Y$ is separated over $S$. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be an open immersion of $S$-schemes. If $Y$ is connected, show that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Here's another exercise I encountered. I'm not exactly sure how to use the properties ascribed to $Y$ to prove this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separatedness of $Y$ over $S$ together with properness of $X$ over $S$ implies that the set-theoretic image of $f$ is closed (see my answer here [The image of a proper scheme is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266005/the-image-of-a-proper-scheme-is-closed/266011#266011)). The image is open by assumption, so (assuming $X$ is non-empty) connectedness of $Y$ forces it to be all of $Y$. An open immersion which is surjective is an isomorphism.